# playbook を、プロジェクトルート以外に配置するには？

Tags: ansible

巨大なシステムのデプロイを Ansible で記述していると、多種多様な playbook を記述したくなります。各 playbook は、デフォルトではプロジェクトルートに配置される想定ですが、数が増えてくると、サブディレクトリを切って、そこに整理していくなどを行いたくなります。

## 質問:

ansible の playbook は、プロジェクトルート以外に配置することはできますか？
(プロジェクトルート以外配置にされた playbook を実行することはできますか？)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

可能だと思います。

```
ansible/
|  ansible.cfg
|
+-- hosts/
|    |
|    +-- production/
|    |    | inventory
|    |    +-- group_vars/
|    |    +-- host_vars/
|    |
|    +-- staging/
|         | inventory
|         +-- group_vars/
|         +-- host_vars/
|
+-- playbooks/
     | site1.yml
     | site2.yml
     |
     +-- files/
     +-- roles/
```

こんな構成で

```
[localhost ansible] $ ansible-playbook -i hosts/staging playbooks/site1.yml
```

とか

playbook や hosts(inventory)は何処にあっても良いですが、その下のディレクトリ構成は、同じです。

role の場所が、サブディレクトリ(playbookのある場所）になるので、それも変えたい場合は、ansible.cfg で、roles_path を指定すれば、playbook 配下にない role も探せるのでいろいろできると思います。

roles_path
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path